# Laravel Application in Nginx Server downloads instead of showing PHP file

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, fastcgi

I'm aware of the duplicate questions and answers but none of them seem to be working for me.

**OS**: Ubuntu 20.04

**Server**: Nginx

**Php version**: 7.4

cgi.fix_pathinfo value is 0.

php-fpm is also running.

Content of the site config file:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name  [site_url];

        root [site_root_directory];
        index index.php index.html;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        location / {

                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        }

        location ~ \.php$ {

                try_files $uri =404;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;

        }
}
```

But whenever I enter the project directory in the browser, it downloads a file instead of loading the laravel app.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What URL are you using in the browser - it should be http(s)://...

Comment: Are you sure `php-fpm` is running? `service php7.4-fpm status` should give you the info.

Comment: php-fpm is running. Confirmed

Comment: Can you confirm the `php7.4-fpm.sock` is present? `ls -la /var/run/php7.4-fpm.sock` and the directory is not suppose to be `/var/run/php/php0.0-fpm`? That's basically the default location for fpm.

Comment: Also check if a simple `.txt` or `.html` file is served. Nginx should be able to do this without the need of an interpreter.

Comment: Changed the location of php-fpm to the correct version. Still doesn't work.

Comment: css, html, txt etc files are loading just fine. It's just the php files that are being downloaded

Comment: Did you reload nginx after changing the location of php-fpm to the correct version?

Comment: Yes of course I did.